# Angular-chart.js styling

Tags: css, angularjs, angular-chart

I am trying to remove extra space around the doughnut chart but can't figure out how to achieve this

Picture with extra space
[image]

Picture with amount of space I need to put the doughnut chart on the left side of the page and grid on the right

[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: I dont know if you already tried but you can change the width of the canvas, but that will change the width of the chart as well.

Comment: @GustavoGabriel yes, I have tried and I don't want the chart to get smaller